# Adding MatBottomSheet to angular 5 app wont compile

Tags: angular

I am using Angular 5 in .netcore 2.0 and My app was compiling fine until I added:
`import { MatBottomSheet, MatBottomSheetRef } from '@angular/material/bottom-sheet';`

and if I remove the import the app compiles fine. I have seen some examples online where it just imports from `'@angular/material'` but I dont have that option I am using:

```
`"@angular/animations": "^5.2.0",
"@angular/cdk": "^5.2.0",
"@angular/common": "^5.2.0",
"@angular/compiler": "^5.2.0",
"@angular/core": "^5.2.0",
"@angular/forms": "^5.2.0",
"@angular/http": "^5.2.0",
"@angular/material": "^5.2.0",`
```

Some of the errors(all cannot find with different extensions):
`../../node_modules/@angular/material/stepper/typings/step-header.d.ts(9,71): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/core'.
../../node_modules/@angular/material/stepper/typings/step-label.d.ts(8,29): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/core'.
../../node_modules/@angular/material/stepper/typings/stepper-icon.d.ts(8,29): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/core'.
../../node_modules/@angular/material/stepper/typings/stepper-intl.d.ts(1,25): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'rxjs'.
../../node_modules/@angular/material/stepper/typings/stepper.d.ts(11,91): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/core'.`

Comment: What is your error ? You need to add those modules in your imports array in `app.module.ts`

Comment: How is this related to asp.net-core ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BottomSheet was not available with the **[`mentioned version`](https://v5.material.angular.io/components/categories)** above. you should consider upgrading angular and angular/material together.

It should be just,

```
import {MatBottomSheet, MatBottomSheetRef} from '@angular/material';
```

also try using,

```
 "@angular/material": "6.0.1",
```

Comment: I am working in visual studio and I have 54 errors now and I didn't make any changes to the app structyraly. It was working fine after what you suggested but now I have errors such as `Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error TS2307 (TS) Cannot find module '@angular/core'` plus all the other angular stuff e.g /router etc. I have checked [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/34681) but they use VS Code.

Comment: do a npm clean and delete node modules and then do npm install

Comment: I have tried the above but I can still see the error messages: I have posted a question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52260210/why-does-my-angular-app-works-when-i-have-multiple-errors) with my package.json