# How to fix Bootstrap error after Angular update?

Tags: angular

I have recently upgraded from Angular 5 to 6 as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52238239/5326036) My project was all fine after the upgrade. But then after a few hours, I started getting errors such as `Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State Error TS2307 (TS) Cannot find module '@angular/core'`.

Plus all the other angular stuff e.g /router etc. I have followed tutorial on how to get rid of these error by reinstalling and deleting `Node_Module`. But Now I am getting this error message:

`ERROR in multi ./styles.css ../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'C:\Users\UserName\Desktop\Software\WeDoKnow\WeDoKnow\ClientApp\node_modules\bootstrap\dist\css\bootstrap.min.css' in 'C:\Users\UserName\Desktop\Software\WeDoKnow\WeDoKnow\ClientApp\src'`

Earlier  **package.json**:

```
`"start": "ng serve --extract-css",
"build": "ng build --extract-css",`
```

changed **package.json**:

```
"start": "ng serve",
"build": "ng build",
```

because I use to get this error `Unknown option: '--extractCss'` and the suggestion was to remove `--extract-css`

Some package versions:

`"@angular/core": "6.1.7"
"ngx-infinite-scroll": "^6.0.1",
"reflect-metadata": "0.1.12",
"rxjs": "6.3.2",
"rxjs-compat": "^6.3.2",
"rxjs-tslint": "0.1.5",
"zone.js": "0.8.26"`